# Can not retrieve new records for cached query

Tags: hibernate, caching, jpa, ehcache

After small struggle in JPA (Hibernate Implementation) caching, I am finally able to cache the JPA queries. When I update some EXISTING records in the database and refresh the cache with evictAll() method, it refresh the cache also. It works perfectly fine till this point.

Now I tried to add NEW record in the database. But it does not pick the NEW record. When I tried to analyze the logs, I see that It picked from database all the existing records only one by one.

e.g. 
Below is my code. Product is my entity class.

```
final Query q = entityManager.createQuery("from Product");
q.setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", false);
q.getResultList();
```

Code to refresh the cache.

```
entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
```

Product.java

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Entity
public class Product {
    // Attributes
}
```

I had 5 rows in my Product table. When I cached, it cached with all the primary keys  P1,P2,P3,P4 and P5. When I add new record and refresh/clear cache, it fires five queries for all the five existing rows to get updated value. But it does not fire the original query to retrieve all the product.

I read few post and they say that I need to create new entity manager. But I am injecting entityManager in GenericDAO using spring. So I can not create new entity manager.

Note: I am inserting new records to the db through some db tool and not through my application.

I want to retrieve new record after refreshing cache. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Below code did the trick. But it is hibernate specific solution.

```
((Session) entityManager.getDelegate()).getSessionFactory().getCache()
                .evictDefaultQueryRegion();
```

Does anybody knows JPA specific code for this?